# headset doesn't works on my iphone

Tags: ios, audio, iphone, headphones

My headset doesn't work on my iPhone (4) 
But it works on another iPhone.

Sometimes when I turned off my iPhone & unplug the headset it works but now.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you make it clearer what you are asking. Sentences would help but more information is also needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. I used a broken paper clip to clean out junk that was stuck in the headphone jack.

Comment: Careful with that.  While it is possible pocket lint is the issue, don't poke with enough force to bend anything.  I would also choose a non-conductive wooden toothpick over a paper clip.